# AWS S3 Bucket Policy to allow only lowercase files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, aws-policies

Is it possible to limit s3 bucket to lowercase files/directories only?

Some downstream systems are case insensitive so I want to prevent any issues.

There's a Lambda workaround, but is it possible to specify this requirement as a bucket policy?

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Enforce lower-case",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal":"*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:KeyName": "lower(s3:KeyName)"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This isn't possible.  The `StringLike`/`StringNotLike` wildcards are fairly simple, you can't create a full Regex-like expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible because:

- String manipulation isn't allowed in IAM policy
- IAM string condition operators do not support regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to have the S3 bucket trigger an AWS Lambda function, which could:

- Examine the object `Key`
- If the Key is not strictly lowercase, then `Copy` the object to a new lowercase Key and delete the original object

However, it would mean that `Foo` would rename to `foo` and a later `FOO` would overwrite `foo`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also, OP is already aware of the lambda workaround.